# ASP.NET vNext Routing - NULL values in the Action Parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Below is the `Routing Configuration:`

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Dashboard}/{action=Index}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Sample",
        template: "{controller=SampleApplication}/{action=ViewApplication}/{applicationID?}/{applicationVersionID?}/{view?}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "SampleSolution",
        template: "{controller=SampleApplication}/{action=ViewApplicationSolution}/{bugID?}/{view?}");
});
```

For understanding purpose, the mapping will be referred as below:

```
Route 1: http://site/Dashboard/Index

Route 2: http://site/SampleApplication/ViewApplication/1/2/ViewName

Route 3: http://site/SampleApplication/ViewApplicationSolution/1/ViewName
```

The 2 Actions are as below:

```
public IActionResult ViewApplication(int applicationID, int applicationVersionID, string view)
{
    return View();
}

public IActionResult ViewApplicationSolution(int bugID, string view)
{
    return View();
}
```

Whenever the 2nd Action is called, the parameters `bugID` and `view` are `NULL`
For the 1st Action, I am getting all the 3 parameters.

In the Routing Configuration, if I **swap the positions** of Route 2 & Route 3, I am getting the 2 parameter values in the 2nd Action. But for the 1st Action, all the 3 parameters are `NULL`.

Have I missed anything in the `Routing Configuration`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34313810/mvc-routing-issue-null-entry/34313857#34313857

Comment: @Shyju, +1 for "The order of route definitions really matters."

Comment: @Shyju, I saw your answer and implemented it. Now, that answer is gone :(. I want to accept that answer. The 2 routes are working correctly. The Controller has a JsonResult [HttpGet] method. It's parameters are now NULL. Should I add a route for this one also? Or the Route Configuration should be changed for HttpGet?

Comment: I had a wrong explanation of the problem .Corrected now. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your current route definition, when a request comes for `ViewApplicationSolution/1/ViewName` It matches the definition of Route2 (since we specified that the other 2 parameters as nullable). So the parameter `1` will be actually mapped to your action method's `applicationID` parameter(if exists). You can rename your `BugID` param of `ViewApplicationSolution` action method to `applicationID` and see that your parameter has a value. Also, If you remove the `?` (represents the param is nullable) from your route pattern, It will also work because your request will match exactly to one of those patterns because we don't have any optional params now.

**The order in which you register the route really matters**. So make sure you register the specific routes before the generic default one. Also register the one with less parameters before the one with more parameters (of same type)

This should work for your requests.

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{

    routes.MapRoute(name: "SampleSolution",
        template: "{controller=Settings}/{action=ViewApplicationSolution}/
                                                              {bugID?}/{view?}");

    routes.MapRoute(name: "Sample",
        template: "{controller=Settings}/{action=ViewApplication}/{applicationID?}/
                                                       {applicationVersionID?}/{view?}");



    routes.MapRoute(name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

});
```

Comment: I saw the updated answer and implemented it. The 2 routes are working correctly. The Controller has a JsonResult [HttpGet] method. It is called through JavaScript. It's parameters are now NULL. Should I add a route for this one also?

Comment: Unless you really want pretty (SEO Friendly urls), you do not need to define   custom url patterns like this. Your default route definition is good enough. Make sure you use the correct querystring  key's which matches your parameter name.